# Use Drop down values in macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Drop Down in excel sheet. It has the values

- NEW
- DELETION
- SUSPENDED

I want to make use to these values to perform some action. Say like if the value of the Cell is NEW is should check that and then work further.
when I write below code in VBA it doesn't work.

```
If Sheet5.Range("B16").Value = "NEW" Then 
    .... Perform some action...
```

Won't the above line work? Can't I compare the Value to "NEW".

Please note: The drop down is in excel sheet. How do I retrieve this Excel sheet dropdown value in macros?

Comment: Do you mean VBA? This is different than VB.NET, or VBScript...  Is your dropdown a Form Control or an ActiveX Control? Is it linked to cell? Etc.  Please provide much more information :)

Comment: Its VBA David. The Drop down is in Excel. I dont know how to say what exactly it is...:(

Comment: Please describe **how** you created the dropdown. Inlcude relevant screenshots (upload to imgur.com and provide the link,  here).

Comment: You have to have something to trigger the code do run.  Do you want it to run when the change the value, or click some other button, etc.

Comment: @David this is how the dropdown is there on excel..http://tinypic.com/r/2ho8wtx/5

Comment: OK. NOw that that is settled, please revise your question so that it makes sense.  As it stands, I now know you are using a **validation list** (not a dropdown control), but it is not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes I am using this Validation list.This list will have some values. So i want select the value from the list and i shd display it by using VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a dropdown, it's a **Validation List**, which is created from the Data ribbon like:

[image]

So the underlying cell, in your case `E1`, behaves like a normal cell except it can only accept certain values.  You can access its properties in VBA as expected, for instance:

```
Debug.Print Range("E1").Value
```

So, your code should work if you call the macro from the Developer|Macros menu, or if you run it from the VBE using `F5` key.